# react-native-maps which api use and how is its costs?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm creating an app based on maps.
From 11 June 2018 Google changes his price plan of the Google Maps Api.
I read here ([Google maps price matrix](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)) that for mobile application it's unilimited free.
But... which api use Google Maps in this library?
I try to use the library and for emulator not use Google API KEY. In this way i'm not sure that i use only free plan.

How i understand how calculate my costs? If there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all information about it.

react-native-maps use Maps SDK for iOS and Android.

This page [Google Maps Costs](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_310418505332-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20%20Google%20Maps%20Price-KWID_43700037673597623-aud-669510846654:kwd-122402743209-userloc_1008430&utm_term=KW_google%20maps%20price-ST_google%20maps%20price&gclid=Cj0KCQiA7OnxBRCNARIsAIW53B-k0dDkZhbzIu7rk_Gt6CcUbkiohmmvWZlMs5d6XVq2mj5Yz-gHMZMaAsRcEALw_wcB) examplain that for SDK there aren't costs.

I tried to enable only SDK Api and check report monitor on Google Cloud console
[image: Reporting use of Google Maps Api]

In this way you can use dynamic maps, use marker in your react application without costs.

It is different if you use search api or geocode api. This api follow the common cost of api reported in previous link.

In this case you can use mix of Google Maps SDK and Open Street maps API